# Angular Validator check if input is number

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to perfom form validation in Angular 9 to check if the value of a certain input is a number (integer or decimal).

I therefore created the following custom validator:

```js
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

export class NumberValidator {
    static number(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
        if (typeof +control.value === "number") return null;
        return { notANumber: "The value is not a number"};
    };
}
```

It works fine for an integer or decimal input, telling my that it's valid, however it also tells me that the following string value for example "foo" is valid.

How can I fix that?

Comment: + makes string as NaN which type of is number remove it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+` makes string as `NaN` which type of is number remove it. or  if u have to check one more plus of number then

```
 if (typeof +control.value === "number" && !isNaN(+control.value)) return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

"+" convert variable to number ( +control.value )

So in your example you convert control.value to the number, and then check if this variable is a number. In this way it will be always a number

You need to check:

```
if Number(control.value) == NaN 
// returns true if control.value is string
// else returns parsed number
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the problem comes from the fact that JavaScript returns the type of **NaN** to be **number**. So maybe add additional check if the input is also not equal to **NaN**.

Answer (score 0):

If the user changes the value in the input, the value becomes a string like "123".
This is a string but (in your case) it should be valid. So you have to check if this is parsable.

Better:  you can set the input type from  text to number

```
<input type="number" ...
```

Then it's always a number. 
in addition: you can set the built-in validators min an max: https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators

Answer (score 0):

Drawback is that you cannot use type="number" you need to use type="text" on the input but. But here is my solution as ValidatorFn:

```
function notANumber(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const value = control.value
    let nV = value
    if (typeof value == 'string') {
      nV = value.replace(',', '.')
    }
    return (Number.isNaN(Number(nV)) && !control.pristine) ? {notANumber: true} : null;
  };
}
```